# Android/Java Global Function

Tags: java, android, singleton, global

I'm thinking to make a singleton function which given some input from one of many threads, the function returns its calculation.  In particular I'll be putting said function into 'Application.java' and accessing it via

```
retval = ( (SomeAppName) this.getApplication()).Foo(value 1, value 2);
```

is that thread safe?

Comment: The contents of the method and where you call it are more important the the way in which you access it.

Comment: A singleton is a specific design (anti)pattern for objects. What do you mean by a "singleton function"?

Comment: For example if i want to manipulate dynamic moving objects in 3space. Command(&DynamicObject).   The command class will make a decision on what to do based off of variables read from that dynamic object.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on what the function does. If it doesn't access instance variables and doesn't call other non-thread safe functions, then it's thread safe; otherwise it's not. Remember that anything that isn't explicitly thread safe isn't meant to work properly with multiple threads at once.